# pg_settings discrepancy between psql and npgsql

Tags: postgresql, psql, npgsql

When connecting to a pg 11 instance and executing

```
select setting, source from pg_settings
where name='tcp_keepalives_interval';
```

I get two different responses between connecting via psql and a script with `using Npgsql;`

The command line psql client returns

```
0   | default
```

while the Npgsql script will return

```
75  | default
```

75 matches `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl` but I still would have expected 0.

What is the cause of this discrepancy and how can I account for it generally in C# with Npgsql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into my crystal ball, I see that your database server is not on Windows and the `psql` session is running on the database server. Your `psql` session is connected via UNIX sockets (a `local` connection).

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-KEEPALIVES-INTERVAL) says (emphasis mine):

> `keepalives_count`
>
> Controls the number of TCP keepalives that can be lost before the client's connection to the server is considered dead. A value of zero uses the system default. **This parameter is ignored for connections made via a Unix-domain socket, or if keepalives are disabled.** It is only supported on systems where `TCP_KEEPCNT` or an equivalent socket option is available; on other systems, it has no effect.

If you connect with `psql` via TCP, you should see 75 as well.

Comment: I see, so that's how that particular behavior manifests. Not a big deal obviously, but different `setting` values without a different `source` (`default` in all cases) seems like a gotcha.